# Halo MCC (PC) unable to access campaigns other than Halo Reach

Tags: pc, halo-reach, halo-the-master-chief-collection, halo

I downloaded Halo MCC (Master Chief collection - PC version) from Microsoft store after redeeming my Xbox game pass ultimate. The game showed that it was included with my XGP.

Under Campaigns menu, I was only able to select Halo Reach (all other campaigns were disabled). I assumed that the other campaigns will be unlocked later.

Today, I finished all missions within Halo Reach campaign. **However, I'm still not able to select other campaigns (they are all disabled except Reach)**.

1. Are there other folks facing these issues? Why are the other campaigns locked?
2. Is there a customer care that we can reach out to for support?

#### Screenshot of the issue

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're releasing the individual campaigns/games one after the other. Even if you own the whole collection or have access to it you'll have to wait for the individual releases.

Comment: Hmm...I see. Thanks for your response. Do you know about the timeline for the release of other games? I read somewhere that others will be released sometime around 2020. I couldn't find anything specific.

Comment: It has not yet been announced a specific date for other Halo. But they should be released before Halo Guardian in 2020.

Comment: Is there a link to this please?  This appears to be blatant false advertising or at an absolute minimum unethical advertising.  If I purchase "a collection of games" I don't expect to be able to play just one of them.  Clearly some executive at 343 decided to ignore all other advice and launch it early for the holiday season.  Nowhere on the Steam page for it (below) does it mention that only one game can be played. The game itself provides zero feedback on why the other 5 games are greyed out-leading to confusion.

https://store.steampowered.com/app/976730/Halo_The_Master_Chief_Collection/

Comment: This has been known since the reveal of MCC on PC and has been stated many many times both via community posts, developer updates on steam etc. You are able to purchase just Reach instead of the whole collection if you wished.

Comment: FYI latest blog post suggests they're working on releasing Halo CE Anniversary for the PC in January 2020.